# Cartesian Product of Singleton and $\mathbb{R}$ Open In $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm having difficulty seeing how $X=\{x\times y:y=0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Being open would imply for any point $x\in X$, I can find a neighborhood around it contained in $X$, but I don't think any such neighborhood $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ is contained in $X$, as taking product with $c\times d$ takes us out of $X$.

The topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is the usual topology.

I ask this question, because in Munkres Section 23, Example 5, the author states $X=\{x\times y:y=0 \}\cup \{x\times y:x>0\land y=1/x\}$ is not connected... And, I just realize as I'm typing this that in the subspace topology, a separation need not consist of open sets.

Thanks to everyone that replied.

Comment: What is the topology?

Comment: Who said it is open?

Comment: Updated the original post; I realized whilst updating that in the subspace topology, the separation does not need to be comprised of open sets, just that the union of the sets must be the subspace and that the sets in the separation do not contain any of eachother's limit points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set in Munkre's exercise. $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}: xy<1\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}: xy>\frac 1 2\}$ are open sets in $\mathbb R^{2}$. Take their intersections with $X$ to get two disjoint open sets in the subspace topology whose union is $X$.